# How to properly filter mongodb query in go

Tags: mongodb, go

I've seen some similar questions but unfortunately my problem is not that i get an error but rather that the query in question is returning null when it shouldn't

```
    filter := bson.M{"EntryDate": bson.M{"$gte": fromDate, "$lt": toDate}}

    res, err := db.collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var results []scrapper.Entry

    for res.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem scrapper.Entry
        res.Decode(&elem)
        results = append(results, elem)
    }
    return &results
```

this is the code, the from and to dates have been gathered using

```
    fromDate := time.Now().AddDate(0,0,-1)
    toDate := time.Now()
```

and

```
        date := time.Now()
    fromDate := time.Date(date.Year(), date.Month(), date.Day(), 0, 0, 1, 0, time.UTC)
    toDate := time.Date(date.Year(), date.Month(), date.Day(), 23, 59, 59, 0, time.UTC)
```

neither approach was fruitful and both return nil, but using

```
.find({
    entrydate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-03-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2020-03-29T23:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

on the terminal does work

Comment: before this approach i was saving the date as a string and checking for equality (all coe being the same other than the filter), that worked, but i decided to change the system to allow querying for a range of dates, so i started saving the data as time.Time entry on the db is correct eg `"entrydate" : ISODate("2020-03-29T17:41:20.609Z")` and using .find in the terminal works, leaving me to wonder whats wrong with the code, specially as i get no errors, just a nil response

Comment: Could it be because you're searching for `EntryDate` but the field is named `entryDate`?

Comment: @BurakSerdar the data is entered by marshalling a field called EntryDate, however that is being turned into entrydate (all lower case) (not sure why but thats a question for another time) filtering for entrydate all lowercase works, thx

Comment: Probably your struct has a `bson:"entryDate"` tag

Comment: @BurakSerdar it has no tag, which is why i guessed i assumed it would use the fields name and again, it insn't recorded as entryDate but as entrydate as seen here ` "entrydate" : ISODate("2020-03-29T17:41:20.609Z") ` once again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

when `db.collection.ReplaceOne` gets a struct it records all field names in all lower case, thats why when using the previously right field name for the find filter the return is nil as the field does not exist.